# Expanding content areas using jQuery animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using the animate function in jQuery to re-size a content area when the user hovers over the element.

The script works fine but I cant work out how to stop the script from resizing more than once if the element is hovered over more than once.

I have created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zxm9S/) I have also added the js I used.

```
var minheight = $('.section-fade').css("height");
$('.section-fade').hover(

function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: $('.childsection').height()
    }, 1000);
},

function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: minheight
    }, 1000);
});
```

Any ideas would be very much welcomed.

Cheers

Comment: Do you mean if the element is hovered, and again before the second animation is done (i.e. the `onmouseout` function is completed)?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `.stop()`.

`.stop()` will cancel all animations on an object.

http://jsfiddle.net/zxm9S/1/

```
var minheight = $('.section-fade').css("height");
$('.section-fade').hover(

function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        height: $('.childsection').height()
    }, 1000);
},

function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        height: minheight
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know about `.stop()`. Thanks :)

Comment: This is why I love this site.  It's such a great learning tool.  Even if you're just reading the questions